# VB.Net Application does not start for some clients

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, class

I'm not too sure how to explain this issue, it seems pretty vague.
Two clients using my application have reported that the application simply does not open at all, it's working perfectly fine for other clients.

I do not have access to their computers, so it's difficult to work with this issue myself.

I have contacted one of the clients and have given him many trial and error suggestions to fix the issue - He has the correct .Net Framework (4.0) installed.
When I sent him a version of the application with no code in the main form, he is able to run it, the problem starts to happen when the form class is initiated.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class frmMain
    ...
End Class
```

The class - even with the code removed - causes the issue.
With all the code left alone, the client gets no response from running the program at all (does not appear in task manager).
But with the code removed from the class, the client gets a "Application has stopped working." error, but with no details provided.

What could cause such an odd issue?

I tried changing from x86 to 'Any CPU' as suggested from somewhere I searched on Google but that had no effect. I'm not sure how to add error handling to the form class initialization so I'm not sure how to get any error information from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The often unhelpful "Application has stopped working" message is displayed when an unhandled exception is raised in the Application domain.

I assume you have your own `Sub Main` method rather than using the built-in Startup Object project property. In your `Main` method attach an event handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.HnhandledException` and writing the exception report to disk somewhere (don't forget to recurse `ex.InnerException`), then you can use this to analyse the problem.

Comment: "Attach an event handler to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException"    

Could you explain this a little? I tried the method [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2949/Managing-Unhandled-Exceptions-in-NET) but wasn't sure how to attach event handler to UnhandledException.  

In Sub Main I tried:
`Try Application.Run(frmMain)`
`Catch Throw New InvalidOperationException("") End Try`  

But the client doesn't get the UnhandledException error so I assume my implementation method is poor, I don't understand it very well.

Comment: You don't need `Try/Catch` in your `Sub Main`. The syntax looks like this: `AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandlerMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there are any exception related to that application in the windows logs? There might me something on your client's machine that hinders your application from successfully opening. Kindly post here any logs that you may find.